# How can I deserialize xml in f# using the xml attibutes as the object names?

Tags: xml, f#, deserialization

I'm making a solution that uses an awful lot of strings that need to be shared between projects. So to avoid typos I'm making an XML file that holds all these strings for the other projects to access...

For that to work I of course need an XML Deserializer to convert my xml data into objects...

My XML file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Strings>
    <String Name="string1">foo</String>
    <String Name="string2">bar</String>
    <String Name="string3">baz</String>
</Strings>
```

I need to be able to access my data like this: `string1.Value`. That is, using the attribute as the object name, and the data as data...

How would I do this in F#? and would it be best to use XDocument or XmlSerializer for this?

Comment: Try XmlProvider from FSharp.Data. Examples here: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html

Answer (score 0):

There's an F# XML type-provider that might be of use:

http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html

Given an XML file at compile-time, it will generate the required types to access the document in a statically typed way.

```
type Author = XmlProvider<"""<author name="Paul Feyerabend" born="1924" />""">
let sample = Author.Parse("""<author name="Karl Popper" born="1902" />""")

printfn "%s (%d)" sample.Name sample.Born
```